# expectation and geometrical probability problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

A horizontal line of length $5$ units is divided into two parts. If the first part is of length $X$. Find $E[X]$ where $E[\cdot]$ stands for expectation.
how to approach this question ? X can take any value with equal probability .

Answer (score 2):

Based on your assumptions (or lack of assumptions), $X$ follows uniform distribution on $[0,5]$ so $$E[X]=\frac{5+0}{2}=2.5$$